# ANT_ROOT Path in windows machine

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
Please enter the path of ANT_ROOT
```

what should i put in this line ?
 I don't know the path of ANT_ROOT ? What is ANT_ROOT ?
Is it is Cygwin  bin folder path or some other

Answer (score 0):

`ANT_ROOT` is what it says. It is a folder when you have [Apache Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) automating software build tool installed.
It's required for Android builds.

You can get it here: http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi